# Listar y calcular diferencias de a pares en R

Tags: r

Necesito estimar todas las combinaciones de pares posibles de una lista de datos en R
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo, para A (Columna 1), necesito estimar las diferencias z-x, z-y y x-y y sus casos inversos. Quiero decir, debería volver: -10, -20, -30 y 10, 20 y 30 para los casos inversos. Y luego necesito estimar todas las combinaciones de pares posibles para B y C siguiendo la explicación para A. 
Además, comparto un enlace con un archivo de Excel con mi ejemplo.
Ejemplo en Excel
[Ejemplo en Excel] [2]
Le agradezco de antemano su tiempo y ayuda.

[2]: http://www.filedropper.com/example_1

Comment: Bienvenido Calfiao a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si pudieras usar `tidyverse` es relativamente sencillo resolverlo. Veamos tu ejemplo (renombre las columnas, para escribir menos):

```
df <- data.frame(C1=c('A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C'),
                 C2=c('z','x','y','z','x','w','v','z','v'),
                 C3=c(10,20,40,60,70,10,20,60,90),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

La idea es agrupar por `C1` y generar las combinaciones de los valores de `C2` por cada grupo, lo cual eventualmente expandirá la cantidad de filas, luego por cada combinación, deberemos ubicar el valor de los dos elementos y restarlos:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
    # Agrupamos por C1 y generamos todas las combinaciones de 
    # 2 elementos de cada grupo
    group_by(C1) %>% 
    # Filtramos solo los grupos que tengan más de un elemnto
    filter(n() > 1) %>% 
    do(data.frame(t(combn(.$C2, 2)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)) %>% 
    # Left join con el df original para obtener los dos valores
    # para generar la resta
    left_join(df, by=c("C1" = "C1", "X1" = "C2")) %>% 
    left_join(df, by=c("C1" = "C1", "X2" = "C2")) %>% 
    mutate(resta = C3.x - C3.y)


# A tibble: 10 x 6
# Groups:   C1 [3]
   C1    X1    X2     C3.x  C3.y resta
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A     z     x        10    20   -10
 2 A     z     y        10    40   -30
 3 A     x     y        20    40   -20
 4 B     z     x        60    70   -10
 5 B     z     w        60    10    50
 6 B     z     v        60    20    40
 7 B     x     w        70    10    60
 8 B     x     v        70    20    50
 9 B     w     v        10    20   -10
10 C     z     v        60    90   -30
```

Con R base, también podrías llegar a resolverlo, aunque la solución es un poco menos clara:

```
# Generamos las combinaciones                 
# Solo de los grupos con al menos dos elemntos
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$C1), {
    function(x) if (length(x$C2) > 1) data.frame(group = x$C1[1], t(combn(x$C2, 2)))
})) -> combinaciones

# Nuevo data.frame combinando el original con sus combinaciones
merge(
    merge(combinaciones, df, by.x=c("group", "X1"), by.y=c("C1", "C2")),
    df, by.x=c("group", "X2"), by.y=c("C1", "C2")
    ) -> n_df

# Hacemos la resta
n_df$resta = n_df$C3.x - n_df$C3.y 
n_df
```

Comment: Excelente @Patricio Moracho. En el ejemplo funciona perfectamente, te lo agradezco muchísimo. Sin embargo cuando quiero usarlo con mis datos reales (alrededor de 4000, con distintas combinaciones de C1, C2 y C3) me da el siguiente error: error in combn(x$C2, 2) : n < m

Comment: @Calfiao, Es por que hay grupos que tienen solo un elemento, por lo que obviamente no se pueden generar las combinaciones. ¿Que correspondería hacer en estos casos?

Comment: muchas gracias. La verdad que debería eliminarlos ya que no me servirían.

Comment: Cómo podría hacerlo? Podrás orientarme?

Comment: @Calfiao, si vale eliminarlos es más sencillo, hay que agregar un verbo `filter()` para quitar los grupos que sean de un solo valor. Revisa mi última edición.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona a la perfeccion.

Comment: estoy trabajando en una base similar. Pero tengo repeticiones de cada C2 en cada C1. Y quiero poder calcular las diferencias entre repeticiones. Me está pasando que si no tiene en cuenta esto me duplica resultados. Podrás orientarme?

Comment: df <- data.frame(C1=c('A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','C','C'),
                 C2=c('z','z','x','y','z','x','x','w','v','z','v'),
                 C3=c(20,10,20,40,60,70,100,10,20,60,90),
                 C4=c('I','II','I','I','I','I','II','I','I','I','I'),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Comment: ese sería el nuevo dataframe con las repeticiones. Les agradezco mucho la ayuda a todos!

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de hacerlo es con un autojoin por grupos, de ese modo quedan armadas todas las combinaciones de las demás variables dentro de cada grupo. Después se eliminan los cruces de la misma categoría de `C2`(que darían 0 en la resta) y se restan las dos versiones de C2, correspondientes al lado izquierdo (`.x`) y al lado derecho (`.y`) del join. Al final etiquetamos cada cruce, para identificarlo fácil.

```
library(tidyverse)
left_join(df, df, by = "C1") %>% 
  filter(C2.x != C2.y) %>% 
  mutate(cruce = paste0(C1, ": ",C2.x, "-", C2.y), 
         diferencia = C3.x - C3.y)

C1 C2.x C3.x C2.y C3.y  cruce diferencia
 A    z   10    x   20 A: z-x        -10
 A    z   10    y   40 A: z-y        -30
 A    x   20    z   10 A: x-z         10
 A    x   20    y   40 A: x-y        -20
 A    y   40    z   10 A: y-z         30
 A    y   40    x   20 A: y-x         20
 B    z   60    x   70 B: z-x        -10
 B    z   60    w   10 B: z-w         50
 B    z   60    v   20 B: z-v         40
 B    x   70    z   60 B: x-z         10
 B    x   70    w   10 B: x-w         60
 B    x   70    v   20 B: x-v         50
 B    w   10    z   60 B: w-z        -50
 B    w   10    x   70 B: w-x        -60
 B    w   10    v   20 B: w-v        -10
 B    v   20    z   60 B: v-z        -40
 B    v   20    x   70 B: v-x        -50
 B    v   20    w   10 B: v-w         10
 C    z   60    v   90 C: z-v        -30
 C    v   90    z   60 C: v-z         30
```